# In simulated annealing optimization method, what is the temperature to be used.

Tags: optimization, stochastic-approximation

In each optimization problem, the cost function and its units are different. I was confused about determining the initial temperature to start the iteration with.
As I guess, the temperature should also have the same units as the cost.
If someone could point to a good source it would be useful.
P.S. - I already read the book written by Laarhoven and Aarts on simulated annealing. It's too difficult to understand that book.

Comment: I am prepared to be wrong about this, but my extremely limited experience in using simulated annealing is that parameters such as the initial temperature and the rate of cooling are something a user should simply experiment with.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I read in an article that the initial temperature can be taken as the average of the cost function over a varied set of parameters.